# Merging data collected using 2 Tracking IDs of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-play-services, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

Is there any way to merge data collected using 2 different Tracking IDs of Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) you can extract the data you wish from both properties into your own system.  Say a database I recommend adding the property id to the tables storing the data so that you will be able to differentiate between the data.

There is nothing out of the box that will do this for you with the exception of big Query. Users with a [Google analytics 360](https://www.google.com/analytics/360-suite/#?modal_active=none) account can extract there data to big query.  However I have not tried this I am not sure even that will allow you to analyze data over multiple views.

Comment: Is there any way I can merge 2 Tracking IDs ?

Comment: No you cant merge them once data has been inserted into a view there is no way to move it from that view to another one.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

While @DalmTo is correct that there's no way to do what you ask for regular Google Analytics accounts, it's probably worth mentioning that you *can* do this if you're a Google Analytics 360 customer.

The feature is called Roll-up Reporting, and this article explains how it works:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6096167

Answer (score 0):

I found this add-on for Google Sheets that can help you with that, it combines the metrics from several Google Analytics properties into one Google Sheet, I hope this helps!

[Analytics Aggregator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/analytics-aggregator/pleghgbomnkddeilncbdgbbannlebdif)